# Creating a branch in a customized build process

Tags: c#, git, tfs, build-process

In my job I have to create a custom build process, using the Git default template and adding my own activities from a activity library.
The process will have to increment the application version and create a Git branch for the version released.
I know there is scripts that create branches and I am thinking in create an activity that will run these scripts in a cmd.exe (process called via C#). But, I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. Is this the better way?
I'm using VS 2013 with tfs and Git and it's a web application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the wisdom in creating a branch on build, but I do know for sure not to customize the xaml.

You should instead customize the process with PowerShell scripts. These will be much easyer to write and support. They are also more consistent with the future as xaml builds are going away in the next version of TFS (this year).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like this. I'll see what my boss has to say about it. He tried to alter the XAML before, that's why he told me to to this. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have a question: I have two or more solutions that should run the same powershell script on build. There is a way I can share the same script or I have to add the same script in each solution and call it from the build definition?

Comment: For now add it to both. When you get the new build system you will be able to create a custom task with your shared powershell script.